# How to replace the following code:predictions_ARIMA_log = pd.Series(indexedDataset_logScale['MH'].ix[0], index = indexedDataset_logScale.index)

Tags: python-3.x

This is a snippet of some older version of the code. ix is now deprecated. however, i am unable to convert this bit of code to iloc or loc. kindly help by providing suitable replacement of ix used here.

predictions_ARIMA_log = pd.Series(indexedDataset_logScale['MH'].ix[0], index = indexedDataset_logScale.index)
predictions_ARIMA_log = predictions_ARIMA_log.add(predictions_ARIMA_diff.cumsum, fill_value=0)
predictions_ARIMA_log.head()

:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: DeprecationWarning: 
.ix is deprecated. Please use
.loc for label based indexing or
.iloc for positional indexing

See the documentation here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated

### """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in na_op(x, y)
   1504         try:
-> 1505             result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, x, y, **eval_kwargs)
   1506         except TypeError:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, use_numexpr, **eval_kwargs)
    207     if use_numexpr:
--> 208         return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, **eval_kwargs)
    209     return _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in _evaluate_numexpr(op, op_str, a, b, truediv, reversed, **eval_kwargs)
    122     if result is None:
--> 123         result = _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
    124

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b, **eval_kwargs)
     67     with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
---> 68         return op(a, b)
     69

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'method'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      1 predictions_ARIMA_log = pd.Series(indexedDataset_logScale['MH'].ix[0], index = indexedDataset_logScale.index)
----> 2 predictions_ARIMA_log = predictions_ARIMA_log.add(predictions_ARIMA_diff.cumsum, fill_value=0)
      3 predictions_ARIMA_log.head()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in flex_wrapper(self, other, level, fill_value, axis)
   1878                 self = self.fillna(fill_value)
   1879 
-> 1880             return self._constructor(op(self, other),
   1881                                      self.index).**finalize**(self)
   1882

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in wrapper(left, right)
   1581             rvalues = rvalues.values
   1582 
-> 1583         result = safe_na_op(lvalues, rvalues)
   1584         return construct_result(left, result,
   1585                                 index=left.index, name=res_name, dtype=None)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in safe_na_op(lvalues, rvalues)
   1527         try:
   1528             with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
-> 1529                 return na_op(lvalues, rvalues)
   1530         except Exception:
   1531             if is_object_dtype(lvalues):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in na_op(x, y)
   1505             result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, x, y, **eval_kwargs)
   1506         except TypeError:
-> 1507             result = masked_arith_op(x, y, op)
   1508 
   1509         result = missing.fill_zeros(result, x, y, op_name, fill_zeros)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in masked_arith_op(x, y, op)
   1010 
   1011     else:
-> 1012         assert is_scalar(y), type(y)
   1013         assert isinstance(x, np.ndarray), type(x)
   1014         # mask is only meaningful for x

AssertionError: